# XML/XSL and Javascript Shopping Cart

Tags: javascript, xml, xslt, shopping-cart

I have a university assignment to create a shopping cart using HTML,XSL,XML and Javascript.  I decided to use XML/XSL and Javascript.

I have managed to get a table to display along with a javascript button for my basic structure.  My question is, how do I use the XML data that I have in my javascript functions.

My code can be found here:

http://xsltransform.net/3Nqn5Yo/11

The javascript code currently is just placeholder as it does not work.  What I wanted to work out was how to use my XML data in the Javascript function "function AddtoCart(name,description,price)".

Comment: You already decided to use the XML data again? When the XML is already transformed into HTML, you could just use the HTML.

Comment: I thought that because in the XML I had already defined everything about each item (price, Description etc) it would be easier to pass them to javascript as objects rather than doing it from the HTML it produced.  I dont want to have to define everything as a new object in my javascript code if it's already been done in the XML.  Is this the wrong way of going about it?

Comment: No, it's not wrong. My mistake - I thought at first look you would like to retrieve the data from the XML again when clicking a button. I just gave an answer, maybe that's what you're looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've just adjusted your code here: http://xsltransform.net/3Nqn5Yo/12
In case you want to have the XML data directly in each `AddToCart()` call, the adjustment is as follows: Change previous

```
<button type="button" onclick="AddtoCart('$Product','$Description','$price')">
```

into

```
<button type="button" onclick="AddtoCart('{Product}','{Description}','{price}')">
     Add one to cart
</button>
```

Using `{}` evaluates the variable while transforming.

Example result:

```
<button type="button" onclick="AddtoCart('Belts (F)','Woven Finish Fashion Belt','£21.99')">
    Add one to cart
</button>
```

Additional detail - As I noticed that the transformed script won't work because of this expression

```
while (orderedProductsTblBody.rows.length & gt;
```

This can be handled by writing the script part as `<xsl:text>` and using `disable-output-escaping="yes"` like this:

```
<xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">
   &lt;script&gt;
   ... // rest of code stays the same as before
   &lt;script&gt;
</xsl:text>
```

which results in

```
<script>
...
while(orderedProductsTblBody.rows.length > 0     
...
</script>
```

Saved this adjustment [here](http://xsltransform.net/3Nqn5Yo/14)

Comment: @SilentUK Glad I was able to help you, and just updated my answer with an additional minor detail which might save some time.